# Android reuse layout with include issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-fragments

I have several layout :

```
loading.xml
reload.xml
noresult.xml
```

These are LinearLayout and RelativeLayout

I use them in other layout as below :

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    layout="@layout/loading"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/reload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    layout="@layout/reload"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/noresult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    layout="@layout/noresult"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

The problem is when i create **a generic layout that include these** and **use it in several fragments** (like in a viewpager for example)

When i click the reload button of the reload layout, on a list. It reload another list with the data of the first.

Can there an issue with the views ids ?

Can i reuse the same include in several layout with diferent include ids, but have the same reload button id in the include, can it create id conflicts ? (it's the same question i think)

EDIT 1 :

Code used to add fragments :

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                                        .beginTransaction()
                                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_top, R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_bottom)
                                        .add(R.id.fragment_a, fragmentClassA1)
                                        .addToBackStack(TAG_A1)
                                        .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the group of layout before the layout itself:

```
findViewById(R.id.loading).findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: It is what i'm doing. I even tried to make the group layout clickable, stil the same result :/

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood you. Is it the ListView of another Fragment that is updated when you click one? Can you post the code where you notify the change to the adapter and where you set the adapter to the ListView?

Comment: There are 2 fragments (a and b) added to a viewpager with a listview in each. If i select a cell in fragment(a) it pop a fragment(a1) on top of if. Lets say i do that in the two root fragements (a an b) with no internet connexion, it popup for each root fragment a fragment(a1 and b1) on top of them which contain the view "reload". Now i reconnect internet, and click reload in a1 it will call onclick() in b1 and update b1 with the data of a1

Comment: Ok. Can you post the code where the reload popup start the connection, and the associated callback? Does it work with internet connection ?

Comment: There is no callback, i test internet connexion beforehand. Yes everything works fine, this is my only issue. I'll post the code that add the fragment =)

Comment: and the code that set the onClickListener as well as the code inside the onClickListener :) too.

Comment: i found the issue \o/ not related to the ids nor the xml. I was reusing a singleton for downloading data ^^